# Пожалуйста, помогите разобраться в Паскале

Tags: алгоритм, pascal

В месте, где написано `while (s) do begin` пишет:

> Нельзя преобразовать тип string к boolean.

Пишу по книжке, в книжке указан такой код:

```
var  
  f: text;  
  s: string;  
begin  
  assign (f,'dop/file1.txt');  
  rewrite (f);  
  readln (s);  
  while (s) do begin  
    writeln (f,s);  
    readln (s);  
  end;  
  close (f);  
end.
```

И там дано задание сделать программу, которая открывает файл и записывает туда введенную информацию с клавиатуры. Я написал:

```
program TeleFon;  
var  
  f: text;  
  s: string;  
begin  
  assign (f,'dop/phone.txt');   
  reset (f);  
  while not eof (f) do begin  
    readln (f,s);  
    writeln (s);  
  end;  
  close (f);  
  append (f);  
  readln (s);  
  while (s) do begin  
    writeln (f,s);  
    readln (s);  
  end;  
  close (f)  
end.
```

Помогите, что не так?

Comment: а что за книжка? там точно такой код?

Comment: интересно в каком диалекте паскаля это компилируется... Хотя я в FPC видел i++, так мало ли чего там в С - style.

Comment: `while (s <> '') do`

Comment: "Основы программирования" В.М.Бондарёв, В.И.Рубинский, Е.Г.Качко

Answer (score 2):

в условии while должна стоять истина и выход из цикла, если ложь

s - строка, а никак не булево, т.е. верно будет:

```
while(s = 'blabla')
```

или

```
while(Length(s) > 0)
```

но никак не сама s